# CSS positioning navbar

Tags: html, css, nav

I'm trying to make a horizontal nav bar on my website and I want to use CSS to position it closely under my websites name header and a portion of the background of the nav bar behind the icon to the left. Here is my code

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Oldnut.com</title>
 <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<script type="text/javascript">
var currPic=1;
var totPics=2;
var keepTime;

function setupPicChange()
{keepTime=setTimeout("changePic()", 5000);}

function changePic()
{currPic++; if(currPic>totPic)currPic=1;
document.getElementByld("image").src="image"+currPic+".jpg";

setupPicChange();}

</script>

</head>

 <body onLoad="setupPicChange();">
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="content">
<div id="banner">
<div id="img"><img src="images/Walnut.png" class="nut-image"></div>
<div id="top">Oldnut.com</div>
</div>
```

Home

Preassmbled

CPU

GPU

```
<div>
<img id="image" src="images/image1.jpg" alt="picture">
</div>

<div id="deals">

</div>

</div>
<div id="foot"
</div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Not much to see here I guess it's obvious what I am doing, and my CSS

```
@charset "UTF-8";
body{background-image:url(../images/bg_bodytakeover.png);
}

#wrapper{
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
width:1000px;   
}
.nut-image {
z-index: 1000;
position: relative;
}
#content{
margin-left:10px;
margin-right:10px;
padding-bottom:20px;
box-shadow:0px 0px 20px 3px;
border-radius:4px;
background-color:#FFFFFF;
height:600px;
position: relative;
}

#banner{
margin:auto;
position: relative;
}

#img{
float:left;
}

#top{
float: left;
color: #FF6600;
text-align: left;
font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed",     Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 75pt;
text-shadow: 2px 2px #FFFFFF;
text-transform: uppercase;
}

nav {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
background: #FF6600;
top: 110px;
}

#list-nav{
list-style-type:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
width:calc(100% - 192px);
float:right;
top: 125px;
}

#list-nav li{
float:left;
width: 25%;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}

#list-nav li a{
text-decoration:none;
width:100%;
background:#FF6600;
color:#eee;
float:left;
text-align:center;
display:block;
}

#list-nav li a:hover{
background:#1d8ed0;
color:#000;
}
```

Now I want to have my nav bar very closely under the giant header text and the orange line background to go under the icon to the end of the white content border. I've tried all sorts of padding and margin mixing but its really just making a mess. I have looked around extensively but nothing seems to be working for me what works for others. Or I can't get all of what I'm looking to do. Anyone got any tips?

EDIT:I've tried a lot of padding to get the nav bar to stretch the screen but it keeps breaking the even separation of the buttons and their hover effects, is there another way to sort them evenly?

****SECOND EDIT NEW QUESTION****
I am trying to have my images change back and forth between the two after 5 seconds. I have seen code from other sites and don't see why it isn't working. Anyone notice what is wrong?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle and reference the images so we can see the actual layout ?

Comment: Absolutely, here ya go http://jsfiddle.net/6MP5z/ I think that'll work. But in there you'll see the nav bar is too low and I can't move it up and get the background where I want it.

Comment: It is also messing with my button hover effects as I mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update for comment:**

I've updated the fiddle **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/6MP5z/6/)** to have exactly what you want. If you can't use `calc` on the list items and since you have a set width of 1000px, you can hardcode the widths in by doing this: width: (1000px - 192px) / 2, which would be `width: 202px`

**Original answer:**

If you will always have 4 menu items, set `width: 25%` (100% / 4) on each `#list-nav li`. Here's an **[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6MP5z/5/)**

I also set the margin and padding on the li elements to 0.

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: It is very close. I was hoping to have my the buttons to the right while the entire nav bar is moved up under the OLDNUT.COM header and the left end of the nav bar background goes behind the walnut icon. However this is sufficient. Thank you very much!

Comment: I have another question, would it be okay for me to change my original post to reflect my new question?

Comment: No, ask a new question.